# How to query MongoDB for matching documents where item is in document array

Tags: list, mongodb

If my stored document looks like this:

```
doc = {
    'Things' : [ 'one' , 'two' , 'three' ]
    }
```

How can I query for documents which contain `one` in `Things`?

I know the `$in` operator queries a document item against a list, but this is kind of the reverse.  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MongoDB's [multikeys](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) support:

> MongoDB provides an interesting "multikey" feature that can automatically index arrays of an object's values.
>   [...]
>
> ```
> db.articles.find( { tags: 'april' } )
> {"name" : "Warm Weather" , "author" : "Steve" , 
>  "tags" : ["weather","hot","record","april"] , 
>  "_id"  : "497ce4051ca9ca6d3efca323"}
> ```

Basically, you don't have to worry about the array-ness of `Things`, MongoDB will take care of that for you; something like this in the MongoDB shell would work:

```
db.your_collection.find({ Things: 'one' })
```